# Terminological question - "majorization"

Tags: terminology

Dear English speaking mathematicians, will you understand me, if I say that a certain series is *majorized* by a certain sequence?

Comment: "A series is majorized by a sequence?" Yes. Like in the Weierstrass M-test

Comment: It comes from the German : [**Majoranten** kriterium](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstra%C3%9Fsches_Majorantenkriterium)

Comment: Maybe "dominated" : but I've found no term used systematically in English textbook regarding [M-test](https://books.google.it/books?id=ULVdGZmi9VcC&pg=PA49).

Comment: See for a similar usage : Douglas Bridges, [Foundations of Real and Abstract Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=8BwLCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1998), page 104 : "Let $f, g$ be functions defined almost everywhere.We say that $g$ *dominates* $f$ if $|f| ≤ g$ almost everywhere."

Comment: Yes, it seems possible